# How to add Histogram constraints to Yes when altering adding columns

Tags: oracle

I'm working on Oracle database and have to alter the table '***RETURNS***' and add the columns ***RENTAL_SALES*** and ***INBOUND_SALES***.

```
ALTER TABLE
   RETURNS
ADD(
   RENTAL_SALES NUMBER (14,2) NULL,
   INBOUND_SALES NUMBER (14,2) NULL
);
```

How do I set the ***Histogram*** to "***Yes***"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the gather status  using method_opt='FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE 1 FOR COLUMNS SIZE 254 {colum name on which you want to enable histogram}' .
Check whether it is enabled or not
Select column_name, histogram from
User_tab_column_statics where table_name='tableName';

Comment: How do I run this?

Comment: BEGIN dbms_stats.Gather_table_stats('SH', 'table_name', - method_opt => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE 1 FOR COLUMNS SIZE 254 Column_name'); 
END;

Comment: I revived this error. Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

Comment: Try this BEGIN 
dbms_stats.Gather_table_stats('SH', 'TABLE_NAME', method_opt => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE 1 FOR COLUMNS SIZE 254 COLUMN_NAME');
END;

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to use histograms? are you facing wrong query planes?

There are type of histograms, depending on Number of distinct values the type is assigned.

frequency(top) histograms, high balanced histograms and hybrid histograms.

The database will assign a histogram by gathering the statistics auto, then query on the tables (when querying on the table data will be update on SYS.COL_USAGE$) then update statistic again.

```
BEGIN 
dbms_stats.Gather_table_stats('SCHEMA_NAME', 'TABLE',
method_opt => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE AUTO'); 
END; 
/

select * from TABLE where ....

BEGIN 
dbms_stats.Gather_table_stats('SCHEMA_NAME', 'TABLE',
method_opt => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE AUTO'); 
END; 
/
```

Note: ( If you already created an index before or already updated statistics and you were querying on the table, updating the statistics again will create the histogram)

Another Note: this `method_opt='FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE 1 FOR COLUMNS SIZE 254 column name` will assign the column to high balanced , maybe this columns needs frequency type, so if you don't know the NDV and how much data there its better let the database choose, else you might have bad query plan, and the rest columns will not have histograms created because all columns size 1 collects base column statistics.